# Woocommerce add name to each product for group booking

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

Using WooCommerce I rent out bicycles to customers from different bike shops. Now, one of the shops asked, if it is possible to have a customer name for every product within a booking. I am playing around with plugins like Extra product options or WooCommerce Product Add-ons.

This works on my local test, if one customer orders one bike.

But if one customer orders the same bike multiple times (e.g. school classes), the name is only asked once. But the shop likes to have the name of the person riding the bike, not ordering it. Is there any plugin that can do this or what ways are out there to achieve this?

Comment: This question is better written than 99.99% of the questions here (but I am out of votes for today).

Comment: It was, thanks for the corrections

Comment: Everything is possible depending on your knowledge, skills and time to be spent… Note that asking for plugin recommendations is off topic in StackOverFlow as it's code oriented.

Comment: I have worked before with coded input forms, but those lack flexibility. Unless there is an outstanding plugin for this narrow use case (which I did not find so far) I am almost certain that the link between any form plugin and any booking plugin needs to be coded in order to have a great user experience. At the same time, I am not sure if the form can be added multiple times if needed with clearly distinctive custom meta identifiers for the shops.